# Can you make responsive text scale with div container size, not whole viewport size?

Tags: html, css, responsive, viewport

**Problem:** I want to set a div container to a `max-width` of 500px, but if the `font-size: 5vw;` inside of the div is set to 5vw, the text keeps getting bigger even after the div reaches its max size.

So basically I want to make text inside an image scale with the size of that image, but stop growing when the div texts' container stops growing.

**Main Question:** Is there a way for me to have `font-size: 5vw` *scale with the size of its container div*, and *not* the whole viewport?

Comment: `vw` is the viewport width, not any container's width. so, use `%` instead

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to use %, but I would like the text to re-size in real time as the viewport changes. With %, I the text size stays the same once it is rendered. 

I have considered using @media query, but I feel like there has to be a simpler solution than that.

Comment: this may answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-size-of-container